# Django Oscar user verification email

Tags: django, django-oscar, django-email

I have a simple installation of Django Oscar project. I would like to know how to send user verification email so that all new users registered email IDs can be verified? By default Oscar registers new users and sends registration email to users.

Comment: you can check this link(https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef) out, it gives implementation for django, and then you can extend on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

Registration email function in **RegisterUserMixin** class (customer -> mixin), It use in customer view.  so 
You want to override **form_valid** function in **AccountRegistrationView** class (customer -> views.py)